# Spam Email Delivery and MX Records

Tags: spam, mx-record, a-record

I hope this is an appropriate post.

We've had some sites on VPS's hit with a recent hack. The hacks were cleared up, the sites were set as "devious/dangerous" by Google were re-scanned by Google in Webmaster Tools and cleared. When checked on MXtoolbox none of the sites in question appear on any blacklist nor does the server IP. I've checked countless other services like this and none of which have any of the sites or servers on the blacklist.

The way we typically run this is that when we launch a site we tie A Records to the site we're hosting, this way client emails don't go down and it's a smooth process for their business.

We do not host or manage emails here, most of which are off site either with GSuite or Exchange like services. So for example:

**Client A:** Site was hacked, cleaned, cleared by Google | Norton and McAfee. Sucuri results come back as a clean site that is on no blacklists. MXToolbox same results

- A Records pointed to us
- MX Pointed to Microsoft
- Full DNS Records located at GoDaddy
- Their messages are going to spam, consistently.

Would this have anything to do with the website? It's a very hard issue to nail down I understand, and I've read countless amounts of articles none of which have inferred anything about a website being the issue. I've also had clients, some hosted by us, others not, who've been hacked and not been filtered to Spam.

I'm just trying to point them in the right direction and based on the conversation I've had with my hosting company, the issue is likely only one that can be solved by the company hosting the emails. I've checked the source files of the emails and not once seeing our Server IP in the source (not sure if that even means anything but just trying to explore all avenues).

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why don't you blacklist that site?  It doesn't happen on its own.

Comment: If the website has legitimate DNS setting, including the reverse DNS, it will not be recognized as spam.

Comment: In case the webpage not sending lot of messages (and no spam) the webpage should not be the issue as mail service works independently even on different location / IPs. It would be great to have headers form some "spam" e-mail. It would be nice to know at least the domain to check the DNS stuff (it can be SPF, DKIM,...) next to it in headers could be also some hints for that. This will be some specific stuff so on general notes I am afraid it will not be solved :-(.

Comment: @KamilJ I tend to have the same line of thinking as you. Would it be helpful if I provided some of that but edited out the site name? For obvious reasons I don't want the URL indexed on here in Google results.

Comment: It may be much harder without the domain name as it could be even some typo so even with editing some stuff may be hidden :-(. Important is MX (for e-mail delivery) and other stuff for sending e-mail are in the DNS zone definition as TXT (mainly SPF - Sender Policy Framework). These has to be checked. Some e-mail header (even filtered for the email / domain) would be also great ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It most definitely could have something to do with the website.

This should really be a comment but I haven't got the rep to do that yet.

Have you got your web server access/error logs? Dig through them and look for any odd requests (keep in mind they could have been altered).

Did you restore the VPS from a backup? Files on the VPS could have been modified and a backdoor could have been inserted. It is best to wipe/restore the VPS from a previously made backup.

What plugins / extensions are running on the web server? Any odd files in directories writable by the user that the web server runs as? What distribution is the server running? Kernel version?

Knowing the above can assist in getting a better answer. If examining the above does not show any obvious vulnerable services, there is probably something in the content you are hosting that allows for such a breach to occur (may be visible in web server logs).

Comment: Even if the site is completely cleaned, cleared and MX is elsewhere? We don't even store DNS on our servers. Clients that weren't hacked and on the same VPS aren't experiencing this issue at all. Adding another layer, the clients that are experiencing spam filtering issues are also ones that send out a fair amount of solicitation emails. So that easily could be the reason as well. I've been typically in regular communication over email with clients that have suffered hacks over the years and I've never seen anything like this. Usually the site is restored, we updates everything and zippy do da

Comment: We are speculating heavily as we do not know anything about the site's content. For all we know it could have contained a PHP mailer connected to that client's mail with hard coded plaintext credentials. I would begin with obtaining and examining the logs of the breached site.

Comment: @NDWest12 I had spam filtering issues.  Although I fixed the reverse DNS configuration,  some emails continued being rejected by some servers.  It turned out the issue was the return address showed some company name instead of client domain.  I forget the name now, but apparently it is some sub company of the hosting company I work with. That sub company owns millions of domains.  Nothing I could do other than changing hosting soon.  Have you done some reverse DNS testing?

Comment: @YevhenStasiv Would there be a phrase to search in the log to see if emails were sent? I've checked the directories within our hosting account and see no outbound messages from our server

Comment: @Mugé where would I check the reverse DNS? Historically, we only manage the change of the A Record. 12 years using the same host and never an issue like that but absolutely worth exploring

Comment: @NDWest12 sorry took me a while to reply.  It is not standard practice for me, so I was looking for my notes on how I did the rDNS (reverse DNS).  I have a WHM account, a reseller account.  On WHM, on DNS zone, create a PTR record.  If you know the IP of the domain in question, this will be reversed by adding to the end (dot).addr.arpa.  You can find details on how to go about it online.  Then, using PuTTY, where the domain resides, type  dig(space) -x (space) IP-number of the domain in question.  This should give you the name of the website.  If it is different, it is a problem.

Comment: @NDWest12 Since I am second guessing, I am not sure if this applies to you.  However, on MXTools, you would have been given this warning if you dig deeper.

Comment: @Mugé ok sounds good. Yeah I don't get any warnings when on MXToolbox, I've scanned both the shared IP of the VPS and the domain name itself, always comes back without any issues, no blacklists, no warnings, all good. Which obviously makes this even harder to nail down a reason haha

Comment: @NDWest12 I am with same host for 11 years, never an issue with emails bouncing back.  This happened to me with Germany servers, which I think have too tied spam rules.